# Group by having at least one of each item

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, relational-division

Say I have a table matching `person_id`s to `pet`s. I have a list of the ideal pets that a homeowner must have (at least one of each) and, from the following table, I want to see who meets the requirements.

That list is, of course, `(dog, cat, tiger)`. People can definitely have more than one of each, but these are essential (therefore `person_id = 1` is the only one that works).

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| home_id | person_id |  pet   |
+---------+-----------+--------+
|       1 |         1 | dog    |
|       2 |         1 | dog    |
|       3 |         1 | cat    |
|       4 |         1 | tiger  |
|       5 |         2 | dog    |
|       6 |         2 | cat    |
|       7 |         3 | <null> |
|       8 |         4 | tiger  |
|       9 |         4 | tiger  |
|      10 |         4 | tiger  |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

I've been able to check who has a tiger or a cat by running:

```
select person_id, pet 
from house 
group by person_id having pet in ('dog','cat','tiger'),
```

but obviously this gives the `person_id`s that have at least one of those pets – not all of them.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing this is to count how many different pets each person has and to compare it (i.e. join it) with the total number of different pets:

```
SELECT person_id
FROM   (SELECT   person_id, COUNT(DISTINCT pet) AS dp
        FROM     pets
        GROUP BY person_id) a
JOIN   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pet) AS dp FROM pets) b ON a.dp = b.dp
```

EDIT:
If just some pets are considered "ideal", and this list is known upfront, the query can be greatly simplified by introducing this information in a `where` clause:

```
SELECT   person_id
FROM     pets
WHERE    pet IN ('dog', 'cat', 'tiger')
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT pet) = 3
```

Comment: So the problem with this is that some pets e.g. `rabbits`  don't work, and this would "pollute" the results. Thanks though!

Comment: @miguel5 For some reason I misunderstood the question as if there cannot be non-ideal pets in the table. See my edited answer with an improved query.

Comment: Thank you!! (and to be fair I hadn't said that that was a requirement)

Answer (score 2):

```
select person_id
from house 
where pet = 'dog'
intersect
select person_id
from house 
where pet = 'cat'
intersect
select person_id
from house 
where pet = 'tiger'
```

You can use `intersect` to get people who have all the 3 pets.

Comment: The issue with this is that the actual query requires a couple of joins, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by counting each pet individually, like this:

```
select
    person_id 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING 3 = (
    MAX(CASE pet WHEN 'dog' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+   MAX(CASE pet WHEN 'cat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+   MAX(CASE pet WHEN 'tiger ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)
```

Each `MAX` in a group would be either `1` when the person has the corresponding pet, or `0` when the person doesn't have that kind of pet. Groups with at least one of each would produce the sum of `3` in the filter of the `HAVING` clause.